# Encoding a timestamp to the least amount of characters

Tags: c, encoding, logic

I need to create a barcode that contains, among other data, a timestamp including year, month, day, hour and minutes. Given the limited length of the code, I need this time stamp to be as short as possible.

My idea is to get the UNIX timestamp, divide by 60 (drop the "seconds" data), and then convert it into hex. Example:

- Current timestamp: **1401546126**
- Drop the seconds: **1401546126 / 60 = 23359102**
- Convert to hex: **0x1646E7E**
- String printed to the barcode: **1646E7E**

This way I can go from 10 chars to 7. I also thought of using a different base, like base 36, which can result in only 5 characters.

Is there a better way to do that, which may result in even less characters in the barcode? Is there any other approach to this problem other than converting to a higher base?

Comment: Well, in any language. It is a question of programming logic. I'm trying to find an algorithm to encode the timestamp, not an implementation for a specific language.

Comment: I see your point. I'll probably use in more than one language, so I added a `C` tag, since those languages are `C` derived.

Comment: What kind of barcode encoding scheme are you considering? Many commercial standards (ie: two-of-five encoding, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-out-of-five_code) only represent the decimal digits `[0-9]` and some extra symbols. You could also make use of code 39 or code 93 encodings, but these usually involve a fixed-width number representation, so saving digits is pointless unless you are going over the limit. Can you tell us which 2D (discrete or continuous) encoding you will be using? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode

Comment: Also, your timestamp might be confusing, since it is actually a time-since-epoch rather than an absolute value. Depending on the system in use, epoch could be either Jan. 1, 1900, or 1970. http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: @Dogbert probably Code 39, 93 or 128, which are not fixed-length and support all alphanumeric characters. I appreciate your concern, but my doubt is not related to the barcode itself. About the epoch issue, we'll make sure to make them system-wide compatible.

Comment: How long does the value have to be unique?  If it wraps in 2 years, is that a problem? 20? 200? 2000? This largely controls the range of values you'll need to support.  Then the target code set is the other problem — you waste a whole lot of your savings by having to encode in hex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the lowest time you want to support and count the minutes since that time on top of dropping the seconds as you suggested. Encode that value in the base the code supports, e.g. base 43 for Code 39. 5 characters in that code allow you to represent a timespan of almost 280 years (43^5 minutes).

Comment: "an unsigned, two-complement binary number"?  Hmm - can't be `unsigned` _and_ "two's complement".

Comment: @owlstead: encoding of the number of minutes doesn't matter (binary or not), it's an abstract number that needs to get encoded in e.g. base 43.

Comment: That is an interesting approach. I will consider using it. Thank you.